# Forms and scrollbars

Tags: excel, vba

I have hit a slight problem which is causing me a big headache trying to solve. I have been looking for a long time for this but i still haven't found how to do it.

What i have is a little script which will create combo boxes on a form.

```
For j = 0 To UBound(ComponentList) - 1
'Set Label
Set control = ComponentSelectionForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "ComponentLabel" & CStr(j), True)
With control
    .Caption = "Component " & CStr(j)
    .Left = 30
    .Top = Height
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 100
    .Visible = True
End With

'set ComboBox
Set combo = ComponentSelectionForm.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Component" & CStr(j), True)
With combo
    .List = ComponentList()
    .Text = "NONE"
    .Left = 150
    .Top = Height
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 50
    .Visible = True
    Set cButton = New clsButton
    Set cButton.combobox = combo
    coll.Add cButton
End With
Height = Height + 30
Next j
```

I have found out that sometimes i could have up to 50 odd combo boxes. This clearly would go off the page. What i am trying to do is create a container to hold these combo boxes within the form which has a vertical scroll bar so the user can scroll through them.

I should be able to create a scroll bar but how do i do it so the scroll bar scrolls through the combo boxes But leaves the label above it and the buttons below it where they are.

I am looking for some help/pointer on where to go to help achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couldn't you put the combo boxes in a container control such as a Frame then add scrollbars (setting the orientation property for Horizontal and Vertical).

So, **outside your loop**, add your frame:

```
ComponentSelectionForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "fraContainer" , True)
```

then add your scrollbars to the container

```
ComponentSelectionForm.Controls("fraContainer").controls.add("Forms.Scrollbar.1", "scHorizontal" , True)

with ComponentSelectionForm.Controls("fraContainer").controls("scHorizontal")
    ' set orentation to Horizontal
    .orientation=1
end with

ComponentSelectionForm.Controls("fraContainer").controls.add("Forms.Scrollbar.1", "scVertical" , True)

with ComponentSelectionForm.Controls("fraContainer").controls("scVertical")
    ' set orentation to Vertical
    .orientation=0
end with
```

now, **inside your loop**

change your code so that instead of addding the combo boxes to the Form, it adds them * to the FRAME container*

there is a great deal of help for this on [Ozgrid MVP Site: Creating Controls at Runtime, On the Fly](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson21.htm)

let us know how you get on

HTH

Philip

Comment: yes but i don't know how to do it. i am writing it through code not graphical design. if i did it graphically i wouldn't have a problem, but its doing it in the code.

Comment: @NoLiver92 the entire form is constructed in memory? Seems like you should be able to use the forms GUI to create these initially, and then manipulate the controls/etc. with VBA.  When in doubt, create a dummy form with similar controsls and review their properties.

Comment: I've updated my code, *and give you a link where you can get some sample code and a sample workbook*

Comment: @DavidZemens yes its all created from code due to the nature of the program for work. i cant do it visually as it will always change to display the data from a file.

Comment: @Philip Thank You i am now at home but i will do this first thing when i get into work (as i cant bring it home due to restrictions)

Comment: @Philip it wont let me do this as it says its expecting an '=' sign but im not sure what to assign it to...

Comment: @Philip thanks i have it working i assigned it to a combo box variable not a frame variable. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Hi, here is a subroutine. Hope this helps you in the concept :)**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Call AddCombo(30)
End Sub

Private Sub AddCombo(num As Integer, Optional gap As Single = 2.25, _
                     Optional ctrlHeight As Single = 18)
    Dim ctrl As Control, i As Integer
    Static lastTop As Single
    lastTop = 2
    For i = 1 To num
        Set ctrl = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Combo" & i, True)
        With ctrl
            If i = 1 Then
               ctrl.Top = lastTop
               ctrl.Height = ctrlHeight
               'Add other codes here .....
            Else
               lastTop = lastTop + ctrlHeight + gap
               ctrl.Top = lastTop
               ctrl.Height = ctrlHeight
               'Add other codes here .....
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    If lastTop > Me.Height Then
       Me.ScrollHeight = lastTop
       Me.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
    End If
End Sub
```

**Things to modify :**

- I have used UserForm_Click() event to call AddCombo sub, so please call
  it where ever you want.
- I have not set the left property, you can easily do it below
  **ctrl.height** line
- Change other properties as you see fit